# $A \perp B \text{ and } A \perp B | C \text{ implies } (A \perp C \text{ or } B \perp C)$

Tags: independence, graphical-model

Let $A,B,C$ be random variables with a finite sample space and the symbol $\perp$ denote independence. Is the statement

\begin{align}
A \perp B \text{ and  } A \perp B | C \Rightarrow (A \perp C \text{ or } B \perp C)
\end{align}

true if $C$ is binary? And if $C$ is nonbinary?

Intuitively, this can be represented as a model such as

[image: Model]

where influence doesn't flow from $C$ to $A$ or $B$. However, I don't know what's the representation difference when $C$ is binary or nonbinary.

Comment: What does $\perp$ sign mean: uncorrelated or independent? What does $B|C$ mean, ${\bf E}(B|C)$ ?

Comment: It means independence. For example, $A \perp B | C $ means "$A$ is conditionally independent of $B$ given $C$".

Comment: Does it mean $(A \perp B)|C$ or  $A \perp (B|C)$? The latter I find difficult to interpret what it means.

Answer (score 0):

We can have that $A,B$ are independently distributed but dependent on $C$.

For instance, consider $A,B \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu =C,\sigma^2=1)$ where $A$ and $B$ are independent and identical normal distributed with mean $C$.